# How to send only one quiz from the database to all users?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a web application that provides the users with short quizzes. The system will check the Quiz table in the database which consists of a QuizID and IsSent column.

If the IsSent column (which is a bit data type) has a value of 0 (which is false), the system will send the quiz to all users. If it has a 1, this means the quiz has already been sent.

I am able to let the application sends emails, but if there is more than quiz without sending it to the users, the system will send all of them and this should not be happened. **What should happen is, checking the database if there is more than one quiz there, send the old created one not all of the quizzes starting by the last created one**. **SO HOW TO DO THAT?**

My code-behind is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendEmailTOAllUser();
    }


    protected void SendEmail(string toAddresses, string fromAddress, string MailSubject, string MessageBody, bool isBodyHtml)
    {
        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("SMTP (MAIL) ADDREASS");
        try
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("psTest@gmail.com", "Our System");

            // In case the mail system doesn't like no to recipients. This could be removed
            msg.To.Add("psTest@gmail.com");

            msg.Bcc.Add(toAddresses);
            msg.Subject = MailSubject;
            msg.Body = MessageBody;
            msg.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;

            sc.Send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }


    protected void SendEmailTOAllUser()
    {
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psTest;Integrated Security=True";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            var sbEmailAddresses = new System.Text.StringBuilder(1000);
            var quizIds = new List();

            // Open DB connection.
            conn.Open();

            string cmdText = "SELECT QuizID FROM dbo.QUIZ WHERE IsSent &lt;&gt; 1";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // There is only 1 column, so just retrieve it using the ordinal position
                        quizIds.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            string cmdText2 = "SELECT Username FROM dbo.employee";
            Collection emailAddresses = new Collection();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText2, conn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string emailTo = reader["Username"].ToString();
                        string receiverEmail = emailTo + "@MailServer.com";
                        emailAddresses.Add(receiverEmail);
                    }
                }
                reader.Close();
            }

            string cmdText3 = "UPDATE dbo.Quiz SET IsSent = 1 WHERE QuizId = @QuizID";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText3, conn))
            {
                // Add the parameter to the command
                var oParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@QuizID", SqlDbType.Int);
                // Get a local copy of the email addresses
                var sEMailAddresses = sbEmailAddresses.ToString();

                foreach (int quizid in quizIds)
                {
                    string link = " Click here to participate ";
                    string body = @" Please try to participate in the new short safety quiz "
                                        + link +
                                        @" 
                    This email was generated using the Safety Portal . 
                    Please do not reply to this email.
                    ";

                    foreach (string email in emailAddresses)
                    {
                        SendEmail(email, "", "Notification Email Subject", body, true);
                    }
                    // Update the parameter for the current quiz
                    oParameter.Value = quizid;
                    // And execute the command
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server as your database? (Or express, some other similar Microsoft DB product)

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `date time` type column in your table and set it's value to current date time when you are inserting the new quiz in the table.

Then retrieve the quiz from table and start sending the quiz by sorting results according to date time they were inserted

Another option could be to create an `int` column with `auto increment` set to true. Auto increment by value 1 would be right for your scenario. Once you retrieve the quiz sort by that auto incremented column and start sending from the lowest value

I am a bit confused from title of your question

`How to send only one quiz from the database to all users?`

If you want to send only one quiz at a time then don't use the `foreach` loop you are using in `SendEmailToAllUsers` method

```
//you are sending every unsent quiz to each user here
foreach (int quizid in quizIds)
{
    foreach (string email in emailAddresses)
    {
        SendEmail(email, "", "Notification Email Subject", body, true);
    }                 
}
```

//you can do the following for a work around but ideally you should not use this Primary key

create list of quiz ids as you are already doing

```
//find the lowest one
var quizIds = new List<int>();
int min = quizIds.Min();
```

remove the foreach

```
foreach (int quizid in quizIds)
```

instead just do

`oParameter.Value = min;`

Another approach could be to use the `MIN` method of SQL to get the quiz id with minimum value

`SELECT MIN(column_name) FROM table_name`

Comment: the quizId is an auto increment column. Please tell me what I should do based in my code above.

Comment: If the existing QuizID is auto-incremented it could also be used for sorting for the most recently inserted quiz. Of course this is only a workaround since it would violate the database design principle that key/id must not have a meaning.

Comment: Let us assume we have 3 quizzes in the database; 1, 2 and 3 and all of them have 0 or false as IsSent value (which means they were not be sent to the users). In this case, the system should sends only the first quiz for this week and the second quiz next week and so on. So in brief the system will send only one quiz to all users per week. Is it clear now?

Comment: Use the query I mentioned in the last or update code as I suggested

Comment: where should I use that query?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to retrieve the most recent quiz that hasn't been sent modify your query from

```
SELECT QuizID FROM dbo.QUIZ WHERE IsSent &lt;&gt; 1
```

to

```
SELECT TOP 1 QuizID FROM dbo.QUIZ WHERE IsSent &lt;&gt; 1 ORDER BY QuizID DESC
```

... assuming you are using MS SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

Add a datetime/timestamp type column "CreatedAt" on your dbo.QUIZ and modify your SQL Query to be ordered By the CreatedAt Column in descending ordwe.
Replace the following line with

```
 string cmdText = "SELECT QuizID FROM dbo.QUIZ WHERE IsSent &lt;&gt; 1";
```

this one

```
 string cmdText = "SELECT QuizID FROM dbo.QUIZ WHERE IsSent &lt;&gt; 1 orderby CreatedAt desc" ;
```

Once you receive the list change to following code to return after reading first row.

```
while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // There is only 1 column, so just retrieve it using the ordinal position
                    quizIds.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                    return;
                }
```

All the best.